# Image Generated Not able to See on TabHost

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have Generated QR Code Image from User Input Data. After Generating the QR Code Image i have started a TabActivity.

In this Activity i have Three Options ( `Home | Image | Options` ).

I have displayed the Generated Image on `Image` TabMenu. But at this time I am not able to see the Image. I store the Path in SqliteDatabase.

When i close the Application and Open it again and go to `Image` TabMenu image displays perfectly.

**What i have TRIED.**

Have tried to put Code in `onResume()` also but no Luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Found the Solution to it.

Went through Concurrency of Java, and added AsyncTask.

The work which was taking Much time(Saving the Image), kept in `onPreExecute()`. And Called the Activity from `onPostExecute()`.

And now it is Running Completely.